# Approximate numeric lookup in scala/java

Tags: java, scala, data-structures

I want to have a map like object that has numeric keys and returns the value of the smallest key greater that or equal to to the value specified. For example:

```
val m = NumericMap(1.0 -> "a", 1.5 -> "b", 1.8 -> "c")
m(0.5) // -> "a"
m(1.1) // -> "b"
m(1.6) // -> "c"
```

Something like this would be straight forward to implement using a binary tree, but I was wondering if there was any standard or library implementation of this data structure.

Comment: What should happen if there is no key equal or greater than the value specified?

Comment: I was thinking some default value. I'd probably just have Double.PositiveInfinity be one of the values, so it doesn't really matter for my purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using a `TreeMap<Double, String>` for this.

```
NavigableMap<Double,String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(0.5, "a");
map.put(1.1, "b");
map.put(1.8, "c");

System.out.println(map.ceilingEntry(1.6).getValue());  // shows "c"
```

The `ceilingEntry` method returns the map entry whose key is the least key equal to or greater than the one specified.  It's also worthwhile being aware of the `floorEntry`, `lowerEntry` and `higherEntry` methods which do similar operations.

Comment: This seems like the best option for my purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your map doesn't change after creation (or changes a lot more rarely than it's searched), then the most efficient implementation would be just two arrays. Something like (not tested, <s>might have an off-by-one error in the `values.getOrElse(-i - 1, default)` line</s>):

```
import java.util.Arrays

// assumes pairs are already sorted by key
class NumericMap[A](default: A, pairs: (Double, A)*) {
  private[this] val keys: Array[Double] = pairs.toArray.map(_._1)
  private[this] val values: Array[A] = pairs.toArray.map(_._2)

  def ceil(x: Double) = {
    val i = Arrays.binarySearch(keys, x)
    if (i >= 0)
      values(i)
    else {
      val insertionPoint = - i - 1
      if (insertionPoint < values.length)
        values(insertionPoint)
      else
        default
    }
  }

  def floor(x: Double) = // similar
}
```

The advantage of Dawood ibn Kareem's answer is that you can safely assume it's correct.

Comment: An intriguing solution. My tests indicate that it does _not_ have an off-by-one error, but I'm unable to get a compilable code set as `java.util.Arrays` don't take type parameters (did you mean `Array[A]`?) nor is there a `getOrElse()` method on `Array` / `Arrays`.

Comment: The first was just a typo, yes. As for no `getOrElse`, ugh. At least this version is more clearly correct.

Comment: Nice! I ended up going with the java TreeMap to keep the amount of code created to a minimum and it seems fast enough for my needs. I will keep array.BinarySearch in mind for future applications though, so thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @FletcherStumpSmith Yes, that's what I'd start with as well.